# How to make a method work for Lists of different objects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, object

i've got several Lists of different classes which might containing duplicates. So I need a methode where I can pass these lists to remove all duplicates (based on the sub-property id) and return the list. For a specific class-object this is no problem, but how is this possible for different types (all of them have the property id).

For now, what i got is this (which is not working):

```
static class Product
{
    Guid id {get; set;}
    string name {get; set;}
    int price {get; set;}
}
static class Customer
{
    Guid id {get; set;}
    string firstname {get; set;}
    string lastname {get; set;}
}
class Program
{
    public void Controller()
    {
        List<Product> pl = GenerateList1();
        List<Customer> cl = GenerateList2();

        pl = Reduce(pl);
        cl = Reduce(cl);
    }
    private List<Product> GenerateList1()
    {
        //I know the filling of these is not correct but it should be enought for understandment
        List<Product> pl = new List<Product>();
        pl.Add(new Produkt("60c031f9-9a9b-4cd9-9e4c-3bde8f5e4665" "car", 2000);
        pl.Add(new Produkt("b786db8a-a55e-49aa-9a8d-c9c6f1c757c8" "pc", 500);
        pl.Add(new Produkt("b786db8a-a55e-49aa-9a8d-c9c6f1c757c8", "pc", 500);
    }
    private void GenerateList2()
    {
        List<Customer> cl = new List<Customer>();
        pl.Add(new Customer("176b628a-bc66-44b5-a842-ec81ef7fb0e0", "paul", "adam");
        pl.Add(new Customer("db439316-1d73-47b7-8462-f815966a6394" "frank", "smith");
        pl.Add(new Customer("176b628a-bc66-44b5-a842-ec81ef7fb0e0", "paul", "adam");
    }
    private List<object> Reduce(List<object> lo)
    {
        List<Guid> lg = new List<Guid>();
        List<object> lo2 = new List<object>();
        foreach(object o in lo)
        {
            if(!lg.Contains(o.id)
            {
                lg.Add(o.id);
                lo2.Add(o);
            }
        }
        return lo2;
    }
}
```

### Edit:

This working solution was made by the help of Adam Houldsworth:

```
    lv = Reduce(lv, v=>v.id);

    private static List<T> Reduce<T, TProp>(List<T> listTold, Func<T, TProp> getId)
    {
        List<Guid> lGuid = new List<Guid>();
        List<T> listTnew = new List<T>();
        foreach (T singleT in listTold)
        {
            if (!lGuid.Contains(Guid.Parse(getId(singleT).ToString())))
            {
                lGuid.Add(Guid.Parse(getId(singleT).ToString()));
                listTnew.Add(singleT);
            }
        }
        return listTnew;
    }
```

Comment: If you provide code, provide compiling code. For instance, the class is called `Product` not `Produkt` and `pl.Add(Produkt(...` makes also no sense without `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibly quite easy way of achieving this is to provide a method that takes a function to retrieve the item to compare. Something like:

```
private List<T> Reduce<T, TProp>(List<T> list, Func<T, TProp> getId)
{
}
```

<sub>I have deliberately not provided an implementation for `Reduce` because I cannot head-compile the dependencies of things like `Contains`, which often need items that implement interfaces.</sub>

This will allow you to supply different classes and use the `Func` to generalise the retrieval of the ID:

```
var customers = new List<Customer>();
customers = Reduce<Customer, Guid>(customers, c => c.CustomerId);

var products = new List<Product>();
products = Reduce<Product, int>(products, p => p.ProductId);
```

The support for type inference in the compiler will often let you get away with just:

```
customers = Reduce(customers, c => c.CustomerId);
products = Reduce(products, p => p.ProductId);
```

You may have to constrain `TProp` with `IEquatable` or something in order to get it to work with a `Contains` implementation, but this is the route I would explore first:

```
private List<T> Reduce<T, TProp>(...) where TProp : IEquatable<TProp>
```

---

An alternative is to generalise the functionality over the classes using an interface that exposes the ID. In the face of `Func` I now tend to err away from this route if I am making the changes retroactively.

Comment: this concept looks quiet interesting, but how could i look inside the properties inside getId?

Comment: @RaymondOsterbrink You use `getId` as a method and call it to get the physical Id value: `var theId = getId(o);`

Comment: you mean like: foreach(object o in list) {var theId = getId(o);} ? this does not work.

Comment: works better, but still var gives me an exception: "an embedded Order can't be a Declaration or an Order with Lable"

Comment: @RaymondOsterbrink Yes unfortunately my answer isn't a "plug and play" answer, it was just a window into a style of code generalisation. There is likely a little work required around it to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare that both classes contans id property:

```
interface IhasGUIDId
{
    Guid id {get; set;}
}

class Product : IhasGUIDId
{
    Guid id {get; set;}
    string name {get; set;}
    int price {get; set;}
}
class Customer : IhasGUIDId
{
    Guid id {get; set;}
    string firstname {get; set;}
    string lastname {get; set;}
}
```

Then you will be able to compare all objects of specified interface:

```
private List<IhasGUIDId> Reduce(List<IhasGUIDId> lo)
    {
        List<Guid> lg = new List<Guid>();
        List<IhasGUIDId> lo2 = new List<IhasGUIDId>();
        foreach(IhasGUIDIdo in lo)
        {
            if(!lg.contains(o.id)
            {
                lg.add(o.id);
                lo2.add(o);
            }
        }
        return lo2;
    }
```

Comment: static classes cannot implement interfaces (but the `static` is wrong here anyway...)

Comment: Yes, I edited the snippet above. Thanks for reminding Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

Just define an interface with the id property and derive your entity classes from it:

```
public interface IHasID
{
    public Guid id {get; set;}
}

public class Product: IHasId
{
    Guid id {get; set;}
    string name {get; set;}
    int price {get; set;}
}
public class Customer: IHasId
{
    Guid id {get; set;}
    string firstname {get; set;}
    string lastname {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can merge your lists and iterate over this interface instead of the concrete classes:

```
public void Controller()
{
     List<Product> pl = GenerateList1();
     List<Customer> cl = GenerateList2();

     List<IHasId> = Reduce(p1, cl);
}
private List<IHasId> Reduce(List<IHasId> l1, List<IHasId> l2)
{
    List<Guid> lg = new List<Guid>();
    List<IHasId> l = l1.AddRange(l2).ToList();
    foreach(IHasId i in l)
    {
        if(!lg.contains(i.id)
        {
            lg.add(i.id);
            l.add(i);
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```